# Listening to an mp3 from a website with an iPhone / iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, mp3

I've seen the answers to how to correctly add an MP3 to a website so that it'll play by default in iPad or iPhone - this question is different.

For a visitor of a website -- how can you hear that mp3? Changing the code of the webpage is not an option. The site/mp3 in question is on the bottom of this page: http://187.45.233.63/novenas.php?id=pa30_01_2011 (the mp3, not the video).

Answer (score 0):

iOS (iPad and iPhone) doesn't support Flash, but that page is using Flash to play the MP3 (and the video).

The only way an iOS user could get to it is to view the source and copy and paste the path (videos/novenas/paieterno_30_01_2011.mp3) to the MP3.